# react native how to get return from a promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

my problem is i want to get a json from this function but all i get is a only a promise and why i choose this way because in app that i'm working on it works dynamicly but the only place that i see i can put this promise is render()

this is my code :

```
var userInfo = (async()=>{
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_info");
    value = JSON.parse(value);
    return value ;
  })();
```

and this is my result :

```
Promise {
 "_40": 0,
 "_55": null,
 "_65": 0,
 "_72": null,
}
```

but what i want to get is a json what sould i have to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call this function from `componentDidMount` and after the promise completes, call `setState`.

Here is a canonical example of how to do this:

```
class User extends React.Component {
  state = { user: null };

  render() {
     return this.state.user && <div>{this.state.user.name}</div>;
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_info");
    if (!this._unmounted) {
      const user = JSON.parse(value);
      this.setState({ user: user });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unmounted = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a very good way but after i change screen states still contains value and this is what dont want to happen

Comment: You need to update your question with a code example showing what you are describing

Answer (score 2):

You should return value.json() . Try this

```
var userInfo = (async()=>{
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_info");
    return value.json() ;
  })();
```

In addition, AsyncStorage.getItem is an asynchronous function, you will need to wrap that in try and catch in case if any error happened during the process

**Note**: If you use an await inside a function that is not explicitly declared with async, you'll end up with an Unexpected token syntax error.

```
async userInfo(){
    try{
        var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_info");
        return value.json() ;
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log('caught error', e);
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your function is self-executing.

You should be able to access the value if you remove the self-execution

```
var userInfo = async () => {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_info");
    value = JSON.parse(value);
    return value ;
  });
```

As `AsyncStore.getItem` is a Promise you could also use `.then` method

```
const userInfo = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_info").then((response) => {
     console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Comment: i tested it before and it just bring me back a function not returned value

Comment: if you want to be able to use `userInfo.then()`, you have to return AsyncStorage.getItem("@user_info");